# div 100% height внутри другого div

Tags: css, bootstrap, html, height

Здравствуйте,
подскажите, может кто сталкивался.

```
<div class="container-fluid maincontainer">
<div class="main-left-right">adf</div>
</div>
```

Родительский элемент `.maincontainer` нормально отображается и имеет высоту `height:100%`, а дочерний `.main-left-right` нет (`min-height:100%; height:100%;`)

Comment: Больше кода выложите. 
Если у родителя стоит height:100% - то родителю родилетя тоже нужно установить height:100%

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у родителя нет высоты в 100%

```css
html,
body,
.maincontainer,
.main-left-right {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
.maincontainer {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main-left-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid maincontainer">
<div class="main-left-right">adf</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Магия. body, html скопипастил и заработало

```css
html,
body,
.maincontainer,
.main-left-right {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
.maincontainer {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.main-left-right {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid maincontainer">
<div class="main-left-right">adf</div>
</div>
```